# How to make my list effects work when I'll change list into table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have list of files - and after clicking on one of them it shows the jquery form: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/GSC3x/11/

But now I noticed, that I will need a table on this page, and I want to this list be one column in my whole table, here is the (ugly) example: http://jsfiddle.net/GSC3x/15/ .

I want the jquery form thing work the same way after changing into the table view. I mean, hide everything and make form appear.

How to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all you have to change you HTML structure in a valid DOM structure, e.g. div form and list elements are not allowed as child elements of a table. And close the table.

Answer (score 0):

To make the table disappear, you shouldn't hide the individual cells (as you do with `$(".show_hide").hide();`), but hide the whole table instead.

Also, you are reusing the button that is showing the form for hiding it, but with a completely different styling. That is weird, unnecessary and makes it difficult to use.

Use a separate button to close the form, and don't use the same event handler (`$('.show_hide').click`). The show and hide parts share no code anyway.

Structuring your code like this also makes it very easy to add smooth transitions like fading or, the sliding you already had implemented.